# Виснет Ubuntu Server и CentOS 8 при загрузке с флешки без VGA

Tags: ubuntu, centos, serial

Есть кусок сервера от ALTEL. На сервере нет VGA порта, поэтому подключаюсь к серверу с ноутбука, используя Putty и COM порт. Сделал загрузочную флешку для Ubuntu Server, выбрал ее в БИОСе, перезапустил и... Все. Появляется менюшка с пунктами Test Memory и Install Ubuntu, при выборе Install Ubuntu просто зависает. Причем флешка мигает, сервер ее использует, пытается что-то делать, но в консоль ничего не выводится, ввод тоже заблокирован. С CentOS та же проблема.

Пробовал флешку на машине с VGA и монитором - все работает, сразу после выбора пункта установки начинает выводиться много строк текста в консоль с информацией об установке. В чем может быть проблема? Это проблема с железом или может в Putty что-то не так?

P.S. Подключался через COM со скоростью 115200. Менял на 9600, в консоль начинает что-то выводить, но какими-то страшными символами и проблема явно не в кодировке.

Comment: Вполне может быть, что установщик Ubuntu работает как положено, но в COM-порт ничего не выводит, ибо и не должен выводить, на мой непросвещённый взгляд... Посмотрите [этот мануал](https://gist.github.com/maixuanhan/93c99a533d9f7b198cd8173283dfd787), может, найдёте что полезное

Comment: Или стоп, Вы говорите, что не работает именно без VGA. На другой машине печатало именно в COM-порт? Пробовали отключать VGA от другой машины?

Comment: @Андрей нет, на другой машине подключали с VGA

Comment: @Андрей вообще должно выводить кучу текста о состоянии установки. Плюс там в какой-то момент выбор должен быть. Язык так выбрать и так далее. Ждал час, в какой-то момент сервер просто перестает использовать флешку и все.

Comment: Когда подключали к машине с VGA, печатало в COM-порт?

Comment: @Андрей нет. Выводило на монитор. Кстати перерыл много сайтов и вашу ссылку тоже находил. Пробовал в опциях загрузки менять это, а также пробовал эти опции ставить на самой флешке в .cfg файле. Результат неизменен.

Comment: А есть возможность подключить сервер по Ethernet к роутеру? Если да, то можно думать о вариантах автоматического поднятия `sshd` при загрузке с флешки

Comment: @Андрей самое интересное забыл упомянуть. При выборе Test Memory пишет error setting up gfxboot и Cannot allocate memory через какой-то время. Самое странное, что gfx - это графика, а в Ubuntu Server ее не должно быть. Если же она есть, то неудивительно, что сервер не может ее загрузить. На сервере нет видеокарты

Comment: вероятно, надо бы инсталлятору (точнее, программе linux) явно указать использование tty (именно того, через который вы подключены) в качестве console (см. например [здесь](https://teklager.se/en/knowledge-base/installing-debian-over-serial-console-apu-board/))

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin пробовал в строке настроек добавлять console=ttyS0, 115200n8 , нет эффекта

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin вполне возможно, что ttyS0 - это не то, что нужно. Однако как можно узнать ttyS*, если Linux еще не установлен?

Comment: `console=ttyS0,115200n8` — это один параметр. пробела быть не должно. посмотрите ещё параметры в [этом ответе](https://askubuntu.com/a/1082673/416190)

Comment: `вполне возможно, что ttyS0 - это не то, что нужно` — можете попробовать ещё 1, 2 и 3 вместо 0 (больше вряд ли имеет смысл).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin благодарю, попробую, когда на работе буду